# How to pass functions as props in Qwik JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prop, qwik

**Problem**

In React, we can pass functions as props into a child component when a function requires access to a state within the parent component of the aforementioned child. I was writing code for an application where I need such behavior to be implemented. However, I'm having trouble finding proper conventions for defining functions in Qwik, and then sending them through.

**Attempt**

I've tried defining the function within my interface to see if that helps Qwik to allow this implementation but so far that has not worked either.

**Code**

I'm trying to launch a modal from a icon contained in the header within my application. I'm trying to control displaying the modal by using a store declared within my header component. It's a Boolean value and determines if the modal would be displayed or not. I defined the function for modifying the state within my header component and attempted to pass it into my modal child component.

```
// components/header/header.tsx
import { component$, useClientEffect$, useStore } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import { strictEqual } from "assert";
import Modal from "../modal/modal";

export default component$(() => {
    const store = useStore({
        ...
        modal: false
    });

    function onClose() {
        store.modal = false;
    }

    return (
        <header>
            {store.modal && <Modal onClose={onClose}/>}
            <div 
                onClick$={()=>{
                    store.modal = true;
                }}
            >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
});
```

Inside my modal component I tried to use an interface to indicate that I'm passing a function into my props and tried to set as the function to execute within another icon contained within my child component.

```
// components/modal/modal.tsx
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import { strictEqual } from "assert";

interface ModalProps {
    onClose: () => void
}

export default component$((props: ModalProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Modal</h1>
                <i onClick$={props.onClose}></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
});
```

**Error Message**

When I click on the icon within my header, it displays the following error in my terminal.

`log.js:10 QWIK ERROR Error: Code(3): Only primitive and object literals can be serialized at Array.flatMap (<anonymous>) ƒ onClose() { store.modal = false; }`

**Conclusion**

Is there anyway to send functions as props into child components in Qwik JS?

If not, can I access stores contained in a parent component from within a child component?

Basically, what would be the ideal approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I'm a noob like you in this framework, I've struggled to understand how this works too.

You actually need to pass a QRL as you may read here:

https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/events/

So, here's how to modify your code for the Modal component:

```
import { component$, QRL } from '@builder.io/qwik';

interface ModalProps {
    onClose: QRL<() => void>;
}

export default component$<ModalProps>(props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Modal</h1>
                <i onClick$={props.onClose}></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
});
```

And your head component:

```
import { $, component$, useStore } from '@builder.io/qwik';

import Modal from '../components/test';

export default component$(() => {
    const store = useStore({
        modal: false
    });

    const onClose = $(() => {
        store.modal = false;
    });

    return (
        <header>
            {store.modal && <Modal onClose={onClose} />}
            <div
                onClick$={() => {
                    store.modal = true;
                }}
            >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. This portion in the documentation escaped my memory probably because it was unclear to me back when I first read it why this was even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I'm using `PropFunction` type to define the function prop. For example

```js
import { type PropFunction } from "@builder.io/qwik";
```

and here is a full example of how I pass `onClick$` event as a prop

```
import { component$, type PropFunction } from "@builder.io/qwik";

interface Props {
  onClick$?: PropFunction<() => void>;
}

export const Button = component$((props: Props) => {
  return <button onClick$={props.onClick$}>Click me!</button>;
});
```

Comment: see also https://qwik.builder.io/tutorial/props/closures/

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { PropFunction } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import { component$ } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import type { Signup } from '~/routes/login';

export const ButtonDefault = component$((props: { name: string, link?: string, signup?: Signup, setSignUpState$?: PropFunction<(signup: Signup) => void> }) => {
  
  return (
    <button onClick$={()=>{if(props.setSignUpState$ && props.signup){props.setSignUpState$(props.signup)}}} class="dark:darker-light dark:hover:lighter-light lighter-dark hover:darker-dark font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" type="button">
      {props.name}
    </button>
  );
});
```

i can pass the function as props to my template as below

```
export type Signup = { signup: boolean };
const signup = useSignal<Signup>({ signup: false });
<ButtonDefault name={'Login'} signup={signup.value}  setSignUpState$={(signup: Signup) => { signup.signup = false;}} />
```